# Windows 11 Taskbar Calendar only showing one week

Tags: taskbar, calendar, windows-11

[image]
This is how it looks. I click the clock icon, and only one week is visible in the calendar. How can I fix this issue?

I am running Windows 11, version 21H2, build 22000.493.
Languages: Norwegian, personal keyboard layout, English, German, Greek
Set to Norwegian system language, Oslo Time zone.

Comment: What build of Windows 11 are you running exactly? You can use `winver` to determine this information.  Be sure you [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Changed it now @Ramhound

Comment: I assume you have tried rebooting?  What language packs and keyboard layouts do you have installed?  What locale is your system set to, trying to better understand, your system configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how it looks. I click the clock icon, and only one week is
> visible in the calendar. How can I fix this issue?

Go to Start, Settings, Apps, Apps and Features.  Scroll down the right side to Clock.  Click on the 3 dots and select Advanced.

Now scroll down the right side and do a Repair and Reset.

Restart the computer and test.

If Clock Repair does not work, try DISM and SFC.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Either Repair or then DISM should fix the Clock.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the same problem as yours, my calendar only shows the day name:

[image]

Found [this suggestion from Microsoft Answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/taskbar-calendar-is-no-half-the-size-as-it-is/2b39c0fe-8224-48ad-95c1-c91cd83d62b4) to click the down arrow button several times. I tried it and my calendar resized to its normal size.